# Definition of acceleration and inertial frames of reference

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, acceleration, inertial-frames, covariance

Sorry for my math lacks, I hope you'll be patient even if this question will probably not be clear.

1. How can we define acceleration in special relativity (and in Newtonian mechanics were we apply covariance also) if it deals with inertial frame of reference? We can define a variation of velocity in a coordinate of time [$v_a(t_1)-v_b(t_1)$ in a point] but not accelerating particles right?
2. How we can then define energy?

Comment: See [four acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-acceleration) and [proper acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration).

Comment: how can we define acceleration as a derivative of speed in this cases? shouldn't be something like a difference of speeds and not a derivative? i know what four-acceleration is

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. The four acceleration is just the derivative of the four-velocity wrt time. You can calculate a coordinate acceleration by differentiating wrt coordinate time, but that's rarely a useful quantity in relativity.

Comment: my question is about inertial frame of reference: how can we define acceleration  for the  inertial frames of references  like in special relativity if we couldn't have acceleration in inertial frame of reference?

Comment: is covariance not considered?